# How to perform mass merge for duplicated records in a custom object?

Tags: custom-object, duplicate-management, record, merge

I have a custom object A and a custom object B.

Custom object A is the parent object.

Custom object B is the child object.

The relationship between custom object A and custo object B is a master-detail relationship.

The issue I have is in custom object A I have multiple duplicated custom object B records.

I'm looking for a way to mass merge all duplicated custom object B records.

Please advise is there a way to mass merge dulplicated records in a custom object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce offers programmatic merge support only for [Lead, Contact, and Account records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) using the `merge` DML operation:

> Only leads, contacts, and accounts can be merged

To merge custom objects, you'll need to define the merge semantics yourself, and you can't, unfortunately, take advantage of the native `merge` operation's reparenting support.

To do this whole objective, you'd have to

- Define logic to locate duplicate records.
- Define logic for selecting a "winning" and "losing" records.
- Define logic for how field values from the source objects are combined, or which records' values survive.

  - I'm assuming your duplicates all share a parent and don't have their own children; otherwise, you have some additional reparenting considerations.
- Write code to merge those field values, delete losing records, and update winning records.
- Write batch and/or scheduled Apex to perform this entire operation on a regular basis.

As an alternative to a not-insubstantial project, you might consider one of the many available third-party duplicate management products, at least some of which (I won't name names here because I'm not a fan of the vendor involved) offer bulk merge of custom objects out of the box.